# Who is this "Melra" that Gheed talks about?

Tags: diablo-ii, diablo-series

Gheed is a character in the starting town of Diablo 2.

After the player starts the *Sisters' Burial Grounds* quest, when he/she talks with Gheed about this quest, he speaks a few lines about it:

> I wonder if that old gossip, Melra, is among the undead? Oh, she had dirt on everybody.

http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Gheed#Sisters.27_Burial_Grounds

Who is this mysterious Melra? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this line by Gheed is the only mention of Melra in the game.

The [Sister's Burial Grounds](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Sisters'_Burial_Grounds) is where the [Sisterhood of the Sightless Eye](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Sisterhood_of_the_Sightless_Eye) bury their dead. When the player is sent there to stop Blood Raven, Kashya tells them

> Now, you'll find her in the Monastery graveyard raising our dead as zombies!

Gheed is wondering if Melra is among these undead, so presumably Melra is a dead rogue. Since Gheed knew her, she may have fallen in the recent conflict after the Dark Wanderer appeared at the Monastery, or he may have known her from a previous visit to the area.